# C# XML language file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to have my ASP C# application to be multi-language. I was planned to do this with a XML file. The thing is, i don't have any experience with this. I mean how, do i start? Is it a good idea to store the languages in an xml file? And how in the code do i set the values for ie my menu buttons? I'd like to work with XML because i never worked before with XML, i want to learn how to deal with cases like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to look into RESX resource files. These are XML files that can contain texts (and images) and they have standardized handling of localization/translations.

Support for this is built right into ASP.NET. There is a guide for how to use it and set it up at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(VS.80).aspx.

The walkthough is pretty detailed and should help you to understand the concepts. My preferred is method described a bit down in the document in the section "Explicit Localization with ASP.NET". Using this you will get a set of XML files with your texts and translations in a fully standardized format.

Comment: You took the lead with that link )

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the .Net From automatic translatation (based on .resx) resources ?

Comment: No i don't. Does that automatically translate my menu items, labels and so on?

Comment: They (resource files) will contains your translated string, so you can use it accordingly

Comment: Yes,
It's XML based. Good point is that you can also add non-UI elements,
and get them in your app, when you need.
Example : I store error messages there, and get them if needed.

Notice: on runtime, they are compiled as dll

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, this sort of stuff is built directly into .Net

The way it's done is that for every page you have a language specific resx file.

eg

Homepage.aspx
Homepage.aspx.cs
Homepage.aspx.en.resx
Homepage.aspx.fr.resx

you simply dynamically figure out what resource file to use, and all the appropriate labels come through in French for example.

[Helpful Tutorials and Videos](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/55/internationalization/)

[A Simple Example](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/localization.aspx#simpleexample)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If internationalization in .net is something you want to get into seriously, you might want to consider [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321341384)
 (and no - I have no stake in it)